# Remove Console visualization on Blender Game Closing

Tags: game-engine, export

I create an application .exe of a blender game engine. Everything works fine except when I close the .exe window the console appear. 
I would like to avoid this behavior and just close the executable.
Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: I can confirm that on WinOS a console gets shortly opened before the game's window opens and after ending the game. Unfortunately I have no solution on that. (Tested on Win7 and Blender2.79).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that it has to deal with the fact that the console has to open up the extension files (eg. the .dll files) that actually make the game run. Reason being is that "most" systems will not have the accurate extension files. So, BGE adds the necessary files along with the executable to ensure proper functioning. As far as I know there is no way to "turn them off" because it is a necessary OS function. Hope this helps with your question.